# Application stops after calling DoModal function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

My program is supposed to verify user name and password and open Main menu dialog. However when the DoModal() is called the program just stops i cannot do anything except stop debugging.

```
void CinterfacedesignView::OnBnClickedButtonLogin()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CString username, password,user("user"),pass("pass");
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_UserName, username);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_Password, password);
    if (username==user && password==pass){
        c_MainMenu cMainmenu; //c_MainMenu class has been defined for main menu dialog
        cMainmenu.DoModal();
    }   
    else{
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Invalid username or pass"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint in cMainmenu.OnInitDialog().  If you don't hit that breakpoint set one in the constructor of cMainmenu.  That should get you closer to the root of the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10731789)

Comment: Well being new here I figured I'd give him the best answer I could based on the information he provided.  I don't have the required points to post a comment.  I'm sure that the answer I did provide will be useful to the OP. If you don't agree then feel free to delete.  Thanks.

Comment: Being useful to the OP is not what stackoverflow is about. Stackoverflow is about answers to common programming problems. This isn't. And the question isn't a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) either. This isn't a forum, and some questions shouldn't be answered.